# For inside for get undefined

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have this JSON data:

```
var lists = [{
        "listId": 1,
        "permission": "WRITE"
    }, {
        "listId": 2,
        "permission": "WRITE"
    }, {
        "listId": 2,
        "permission": "READ"
    }, {
        "listId": 3,
        "permission": "READ"
    }, {
        "listId": 3,
        "permission": "WRITE"
    }, {
        "listId": 5,
        "permission": "WRITE"
    }]
```

And this one:

```
var arr = [{
    "listId": 1,
    "confidentiality": "PUBLIC",
    "listName": "List name here..1",
    "permission": "WRITE"
}, {
    "listId": 2,
    "confidentiality": "PUBLIC",
    "listName": "List name here..2",
    "permission": "READ"
}, {
    "listId": 3,
    "confidentiality": "CONFIDENTIAL",
    "listName": "List name here..3",
    "permission": "WRITE"
}, {
    "listId": 4,
    "confidentiality": "CONFIDENTIAL",
    "listName": "List name here..4",
    "permission": "WRITE"
}, {
    "listId": 5,
    "confidentiality": "CONFIDENTIAL",
    "listName": "List name here..5",
    "permission": "WRITE"
}]
```

And with this for and nested for I must filter data from **arr** and push it to **results[]** if is match **listId** and **permission** **in lists[...]**

```
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {   
  for(var j = 0; j < lists.length; j++) {     
     if( (arr[j].listId == lists[i].listId) && (arr[j].permission == lists[i].permission) ) {
        result.push(arr[j]);
     }
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

The problems is I get listId undefined if arr.length is smaller than lists.length

Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problems is I get listId undefined if arr.length is smaller then
>   lists.length

You need to use the respective indexes for their own arrays, i.e. `i` for `arr` and `j` for `lists`

```
if( (arr[i].listId == lists[j].listId) && (arr[i].permission == lists[j].permission) )
```

Answer (score 3):

You could change the structure a bit with a look up table for permissions and use only a single loop for the result set.

```js
var lists = [{ listId: 1, permission: "WRITE" }, { listId: 2, permission: "WRITE" }, { listId: 2, permission: "READ" }, { listId: 3, permission: "READ" }, { listId: 3, permission: "WRITE" }, { listId: 5, permission: "WRITE" }],
    array = [{ listId: 1, confidentiality: "PUBLIC", listName: "List name here..1", permission: "WRITE" }, { listId: 2, confidentiality: "PUBLIC", listName: "List name here..2", permission: "READ" }, { listId: 3, confidentiality: "CONFIDENTIAL", listName: "List name here..3", permission: "WRITE" }, { listId: 4, confidentiality: "CONFIDENTIAL", listName: "List name here..4", permission: "WRITE" }, { listId: 5, confidentiality: "CONFIDENTIAL", listName: "List name here..5", permission: "WRITE" }],
    permissions = {},
    result;

lists.forEach(function (p) {
    permissions[p.listId] = permissions[p.listId] || {};
    permissions[p.listId][p.permission] = true;
});

result = array.filter(function (a) {
    return permissions[a.listId] && permissions[a.listId][a.permission];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes, nice example!